# Export data in parquet file in teradata

Tags: python, database, teradata, data-migration, data-extraction

I cannot figure out a solution for exporting data from the Teradata database in a parquet format. I am using tdload and tbuild method which required tpt script to be generated.

What should be the solution to export file in parquet files from the Teradata database?

tdload cmd -

tdload --SourceTdpid 192.168.xx.xx --SourceUserName dbc --SourceUserPassword dbc --SourceTable AdventureDW.FactProductInventory --TargetTextDelimiter "|" --FileWriterFileSizeMax 30G --TargetFilename F:\Data\data.parquet My_Unload_Job

What changes should I do the command to get output in parquet format?

Comment: The tdload utility does not support parquet.

Comment: Hi @Fred, What should be the best solution, in that case, to get the files in parquet format? Is it possible through tpt scripts? How to export data in parquet format?

Comment: If your Teradata database is 17.05 or later, the WRITE_NOS database feature can create parquet files directly. TPT currently does not support parquet, though it does offer Access Modules that can write CSV to cloud storage rather than local files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the data from csv to parquet format via dask framework. Here post the extraction, using pyarrow engine I was able to convert the large csv datasets into inbuilt parquet function via dask framework